# How to display an html file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, multiline

I am trying to display an html file in my js-code.

It is an ordinary html file that I would like to see. I have already created an IFRAME for this, but somehow I cannot go further...

This is my code fragment:

```
var controlAddIn = document.getElementById('controlAddIn').src = 'index.html';
```

So the file I want to call is "index.html". But it is not working.

If I call it in that way:

```
var controlAddIn = document.getElementById('controlAddIn').srcdoc = '<div><meta charset="UFT-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></div>';
```

It is working, but taht makes it very hard to read...
Do you have an idea, how I can call my entire code at this point, also multiline?

Comment: Is `index.html` in the same directory as the HTML file containing the iframe?

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4gk9wL6b/2/

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it i and no, there are no error messages.

Comment: What are you seeing in the iframe instead of the contents of `index.html`?

Comment: Mabe it is important to know, that I would like to see the output of my html file in Business Central^^ maybe that is why it is not working...

Comment: What is Business Central?

Comment: Do you know Dynamics NAV?

Comment: No, I've never heard of that, either.

Answer (score 0):

**The both file should be same path if you are calling like that 
else you have call the correct path**

```
var controlAddIn = document.getElementById('controlAddIn').src = 'index.html';
```

> save this file in index.html path and open it on browser

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function newSite() {


    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = "index.html"
}    
</script>

<input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="newSite()" />
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://google.com/" ></iframe>
```

Comment: What are you doing differently from his code? He said in a comment that they're in the same directory.

Comment: i did this example for if the file in same path it will work.

Comment: Answers should not be used for examples. They should explain what the problem is and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use XMLHttp request to get Html File Content this code async

```js
function httpGet(theUrl,callback)
   {
       var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true ); // false for synchronous request
       xmlHttp.send( null );
       xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
       };
    }
  var controlAddIn;
  httpGet("index.html",function(content){
     controlAddIn = document.getElementById('controlAddIn').src =content;
  });
```

Comment: I think you mean `srcdoc` instead of `src`. Also, synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated, you should write asynchronous code.